# High CPU load by KVM VM

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, cpu-usage

VMs are hosting Java and they seem to be using high sy% CPU on the server.
Is there a way to limit it via Libvirt ?
Other VMs not using Java in them are not using that much sy% on the server.
I checked it using atop no the server.

Comment: Are you saying that the same workload on the same software, with the same resource allocation behaves differently in a VM compared with natively? Why are you trying to solve the problem by making it slower?